# Nhibernate .Net attribute mapping. It is possible to set default value?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate

It is possible to set a default value for attribute mapping ? Example, if i have this property :

```
private string sDoorLength;
[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column = "door_length")]
public string DoorLength { get { return sDoorLength; } set { sDoorLength = value; } }
```

I want to know if it's possible to add a parameter to NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property for setting a default value. Like `[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column = "door_length", Default="Test")]` or something like that.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize the private field to a default value.

```
private string sDoorLength = "Test";
```

Comment: Haha! No problem, happens to me all the time.